# how to create a facebook look alike gallery with css and jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i want to add to my website a photo gallery in a restricted width ( the height does not matter ) . I tried a lot of types of galleries, but all of them were depending on the width or height of the photo. Then i thought "why not use a same patern like facebook?", but my problem is that i do not know how. I do not need such a complex gallery like facebook, but i need the autoresize clickable photos ( the little thumbnails which appear to present a photo in a album ) and when you click them to expand to their normal size , with left and right arrows. Can you help me succed my goal? If something is not clear, ask me in the comment section, i do not speak very well english.

PS: all my site is based on html, jquery and css.

Comment: You can't resize images easily in Javascript - and it would mean downloading the whole image first which would be very slow for large galleries. You should generate the thumbnails on the server using whatever technology you're familiar with (eg PHP/ASP.Net/Python/Ruby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below CSS property to re-scale an image although as stated above, this won't do your loading times any favours and a server side script would be a more preferable option if you're willing to delve into PHP. If not, feel free to create a div with a set width and height along with the below property and a background image and that should work. The downside is that you may not be able to link the div without use of onClick/JavaScript.

```
background-size: 100%;
```

As for jQuery, you can use the http://fancybox.net lightbox plugin to allow your users to click on a 'thumbnail', view the full-sized image and use the arrow keys to switch between images.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to have a server side resize script that scales your images to predefined constraints (eg thumbnail, preview and full size). There are numerous ways to do this, such as http://www.reconn.us/image_thumbnail.html for PHP.

The simpler method would be to just CSS style properties to have the browser resize the image. This has the disadvantage that the server will always send the large images, regardless if your user wants to view them in full size, but only requires you to set width and height in the img tag.